# What is that shadow in Blight Town?

Tags: dark-souls

Looking down at the sewer like area (in front of the spinning wheel), close to where you find the second fire keeper soul guarded by those "fire dogs", you can see a lurking shadow with a moving tail. If you move to the platform the shadow is nowhere to be seen. It is only visible if you look down on this area.

What is this shadow, a graphic glitch?

*edit*

[image: Shadow is below the glowing message. Upwards in the image one can find the Fire Keeper soul.]

Comment: Can you add an screenshot? Is it possible what you refer to is the giant bug stuck inside a pipe-like structure?

Comment: I had to use my phone. I hope you can see the shadow. I'm standing above looking down at the platform. Behind the shadow one can find the dogs and Fire Keeper soul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a shadow of one of those ugly bug things that is above you, up the stairs.

Comment: Yeah, I've come to the same conclusion since asking the question. :-)